# Laravel eloquent skip() limit() use

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Content::find($tag[0]->content_list)->take(5)
 Where $tag[0]->content_list =[1,7,9,11,16,23,35,56,77,87,93]

This works properly

But I want to use something like this
Content::find($tag[0]->content_list)->take(5)->skip(5)

This throws error

Comment: Very poorly asked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `find()` you actually execute the query and get a collection back. Now the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class has a `take` method, but no `skip` method. That's what's happening here.

Instead you should call `take()` and `skip()` **before** you use `find()`:

```
Content::take(5)->skip(5)->find($tag[0]->content_list);
```